# Why unable to display two inputs in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, textbox, output

The arrow where it is pointed there I need output surname is: lion

[image]

I am unable to get the desire output. I think the problem is in the index.jsp or the NameController.java file

**Index jsp code**

```
    <form name="greetingForm" action="NameController" method="post" style="width: 300px; ">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Please enter your name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td><input name="name" value='${nameForm.name}'/></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Enter Last name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="lastName" value='${nameForm.lastName }'/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

    <input id="greetingField" value='${nameForm.greetingText}' style ="background-color: white; border: none; width: 400px;" disabled="disabled" />
    <input id="greetingFields" value='${val.idText }' style ="background-color: white; border: none; width: 400px;"disabled = "disabled" />
    <input id="currentTime" value='${nameForm.currentTime}' style ="background-color: white; border: none; width: 400px;" disabled="disabled" />
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**NameForm.java**

```
    public void setCurrentTime(String currentTime) {
            this.currentTime = currentTime;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        //my code 
        public String getlastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
        public void setlastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        //my code ends
        public String getGreetingText() {
            return greetingText;
        }
        public void setGreetingText(String greetingText) {
            this.greetingText = greetingText;
        }
        //my code
        public String getIdText() {
            return idText;
        }
        public void setIdText(String idText) {
            this.idText = idText;
        }
        //my code ends
    }
```

**Name controller.java**

```
    public class NameController extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            doPost(request, response);
        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            NameForm nameForm = new NameForm();
            NameForm val = new NameForm();
            nameForm.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            val.setlastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
            session.setAttribute("nameForm",nameForm);
            session.setAttribute("val", val);
            nameForm.setGreetingText("Hello "+nameForm.getName());
            val.setGreetingText("last name is:" +val.getlastName());
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post your code here as text.

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if you click on that link you can see the code but still i will post it here also

Comment: @AdityaBhogte you have use `val` to set value for `lastname` in your servlet .So  you need to use `val.lastName` the same to access it .but you have typo here instead of `${val.lastName}` you have use `${nameForm.lastName}` check your inputs and change it accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines:

```
<tr>
        <td><input name="lastName" value='${val.lastName }'/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
```